# How to prevent Client DOM Code Injection Vulnerability in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Method function at line xxx of .../addAnnouncements.js gets a client-side controlled data for the
json element. This element’s value is used in client-side code without being properly sanitized or validated and
is eventually integrated into the HTML code in function at linse yyy  and zzz of .../addAnnouncements.js.

Script as follows:

```
 function addAnnouncement() {
        try {
                var formData = $('form').serialize();
                $('div.block').block();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "bat.ajax", 
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
  xxx:                  success: function(json) {
  yyy:                      if(json.ERROR == '') {
                            alert("The announcement has been saved");
                            $('div.block').unblock();
                        } else {
  zzz:                          alert(json.ERROR);
                            $('div.block').unblock();
                        }
                    }, 
                    error: function() {
                        $('div.block').unblock();
                        alert('The request could not be fulfilled due an internal error, please try again.'); 
                    }
                });

        } catch(e) {}
    }
```

The following lines may enable a DOM code injection attack
.......

```
if(json.ERROR =='') {
```

and

```
 alert(json.ERROR);
```

Could some help me how to sanitize the above scenario to satisfy Checkmarx?

Comment: The JSON stuff is getting worse every day ... What is "_json element_"?

Comment: Hi Teemu,
I have taken here json as variable...it could be anything like result or any variable

Comment: JSON is a data transferring format, represented by a string when read into a script, there's no "elements" in a string.

Comment: Yes I agree with you,JSON is a data transferring format.Can you please suggest how to sanitize if(json.ERROR =='') { } and alert(json.ERROR);

Comment: I'm pretty sure Checkmarx refers to the alert in both cases. Just remove the alerts. Whether it really is a security issue, is arguable, you can inject almost anything to the DOM via dev tools and user scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code It should be help full-

> JSON is in string format so we can't access by dot(.)
>
> JSON.parse() is used for JSON to Object conversion. Now we can access
>   by using dot(.).

function addAnnouncement() {

```
        try {
                var formData = $('form').serialize();
                $('div.block').block();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "bat.ajax", 
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
  xxx:                  success: function(json) {
                            var json = JSON.parse(json);
  yyy:                      if(json.ERROR == '') {
                            alert("The announcement has been saved");
                            $('div.block').unblock();
                        } else {
  zzz:                          alert(json.ERROR);
                            $('div.block').unblock();
                        }
                    }, 
                    error: function() {
                        $('div.block').unblock();
                        alert('The request could not be fulfilled due an internal error, please try again.'); 
                    }
                });

        } catch(e) {}
    }
```